# PHP form with a select box (drop down list) not showing all values in mySQL table

Tags: php

The PHP project was developed by a previous person.  I'm a newbie to PHP.  The drop down list works but doesn't show the complete list of values (around 130) from the mySQL table.  Each is value has a space between as well.  Trying modify the code to remove the space and pull all values.

Done some research online but not sure about the syntax changes to make it work.  Have changed mysql_fetch_array to assoc but this produces nothing.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "id", "pwd");
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

    $query = "SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE location = 'Location' AND deleted !='True' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

    echo "\nfunction Plant3menu(form) {";
        echo "\nfor ( var i=0; i < form.lstRequestor.length; i++ ) {";
            echo "\nform.lstRequestor.options[i].text = \"\";";
            echo "\nform.lstRequestor.options[i].value = \"\";";
        echo "\n}";

        $i = 1;
        while ($myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "\nform.lstRequestor.options[" . $i . "].text = \"" . $myrow3['name'] . "\";";
            echo "\nform.lstRequestor.options[" . $i . "].value = \"" . $myrow3['name'] . "\";";
            $i++;
        }
    echo "\n}";
```

Comment: Your SQL query includes a `WHERE` clause, perhaps the missing records are being explicitly filtered by that?  What is the client-side code produced by this server-side code and does it contain what you expect?

Comment: can you add what was the existing code and waht you have tried instead to spot the different first

Comment: Thank for your responses.  The where clause isn't affecting the records. Get what I'm looking for except it's not a complete list.  If I run the SQL statement in mySQL workbench I get all the records I expect.As for code changes, I'm not changing much as I don't know PHP well enough to make changes.  The only change I made is the mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc which resulted in no results.

Comment: The number of records the query pulls in the workbench is 127.  I believe the above code creates a blank plus pulls records from the db.  It appears that the drop down list shows 120 entries (1 blank and 119 records).  If I change various record's location field value (from location to none for example), the code pulls different records but never more than the 119.  Is the 120 entries in a drop down a limitation?